# RabbitMQ Management access issue

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ in a CentOS Virtual Machine that has the Network Adapter defined as Bridge.
I'm trying to configure RabbitMQ Management in order to access the WebApp through the IP address of the machine. Configuration is as follow:

```
{rabbitmq_management,
  [%% Pre-Load schema definitions from the following JSON file. See
   %% http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#load-definitions
   %%
   %% {load_definitions, "/path/to/schema.json"},

   %% Log all requests to the management HTTP API to a file.
   %%
   %% {http_log_dir, "/path/to/access.log"},

   %% Change the port on which the HTTP listener listens,
   %% specifying an interface for the web server to bind to.
   %% Also set the listener to use SSL and provide SSL options.
   %%
   %% {listener, [{port,     12345},
   %%             {ip,       "192.168.1.131"},
   %%             {ssl,      false},
   %%             {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "/path/to/cacert.pem"},
   %%                         {certfile,   "/path/to/cert.pem"},
   %%                         {keyfile,    "/path/to/key.pem"}]}]},

    {listener, [{port, 12345},{ip, "192.168.1.131"}]}

   %% Configure how long aggregated data (such as message rates and queue
   %% lengths) is retained. Please read the plugin's documentation in
   %% https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#configuration for more
   %% details.
   %%
   %% {sample_retention_policies,
   %%  [{global,   [{60, 5}, {3600, 60}, {86400, 1200}]},
   %%   {basic,    [{60, 5}, {3600, 60}]},
   %%   {detailed, [{10, 5}]}]}
  ]},
```

As you can see above I have configured the listener to have `{port, 12345},{ip, "192.168.1.131"}`.

When starting the server i'm having the following error:

```
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Logs as follow:

```
Aug 16 16:18:15 localhost.localdomain rabbitmqctl[5630]: - cookie hash: PmW6Wh1PELt7r55GMh8s7g==
Aug 16 16:18:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Aug 16 16:18:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Aug 16 16:18:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Aug 16 16:18:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong with the config?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct config file is:

```
[
{rabbitmq_management,
  [
    {listener, [{port, 12345},{ip, "192.168.0.102"}]}
  ]}

].
```

Tested it:

```
curl -X GET -u test:test http://192.168.0.102:12345/api/overview | python -m json.tool

{
    "cluster_name": "rabbit@mac",
    "contexts": [
        {
            "description": "RabbitMQ Management",
            "ip": "192.168.0.102",
            "node": "rabbit@mac",
            "path": "/",
            "port": "12345",
            "ssl_opts": []
        }
    ],
....
```